# Set up SSH access with gogoc service

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to set up gogoc in order to allow my computer to be accessible via SSH using a Freenet6 Tunnel Broker.

Here are the relevant parts of my `/etc/gogoc/gogoc.conf`:

```
userid=<my_userid>
passwd=<my_password>
server=amsterdam.freenet6.net
auth_method=digest-md5
host_type=host
```

After starting the service: `sudo service gogoc start`

It all seems to be working correctly, here is the `/var/log/gogoc/gogoc.log`:

```
gogoc: Your IPv6 address is 2001:05c0:1400:000b:0000:0000:0000:221f.
gogoc: Your IPv6 DNS address is 2001:4860:4860:0000:0000:0000:0000:8888.
```

`sudo ifconfig | grep inet6` output:

```
inet6 addr: fe80::d267:e5ff:fe07:5172/64 Scope:Link
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
inet6 addr: fe80::c0ef:88ff:fe39:e8f4/64 Scope:Link
inet6 addr: 2001:5c0:1400:b::221f/128 Scope:Global
```

However if I try to SSH from another machine:

```
ssh -6 [linux_user]@[net6_user].amsterdam.freenet6.net
```

I get the following error message:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname [net6_user].amsterdam.freenet6.net: Name or
>   service not known

I have installed and running openssh and I use Ubuntu 12.04

Any idea what I could be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](http://www.gogo6.com/freenet6/tunnelbroker), your tunnel endpoint automatically gets a name like userid.broker.freenet6.net:

> The FQDN associated with authenticated tunnels uses the format
>   userid.broker.freenet6.net, where userid is the name of the end-user's
>   account. A user registered under “incredibleipv6” would have this DNS
>   entry: incredibleipv6.broker.freenet6.net

Comment: A little more info on *why* you think that would certainly increase the quality and credibility of this answer.